# Is there a way to monitor threads in AndroidStudio?

Tags: java, multithreading, android-studio

I have an Android Java app that I am creating in AndroidStudio and running it on a Samsung Tablet (not using a virtual device at all).  I have three threads and I believe that one of them may be getting stuck in some sort of loop because the app severely slows down at some point, but not forever.

Are there some tools available where I can monitor my app and all threads as far as CPU, RAM, etc. usage?

Thanks

Comment: in the Android-studio there is an Android Monitor which has those options

Answer (score 16):

[Android Monitor tools](https://developer.android.com/studio/profile/am-basics) were replaced with [**Android Profiler**](https://developer.android.com/studio/profile/), in [Android Studio 3.0](https://android-developers.googleblog.com/2017/10/android-studio-30.html):

> **Android Profiler** - Android Studio 3.0 includes a brand new suite of tools to help debug performance problems in your app. We completely rewrote the previous set of Android Monitor tools, and replaced them with the Android Profiler. Once you deploy your app to a running device or emulator, click on the Android Profiler tab and you will now have access to a real-time & unified view of the CPU, Memory, & Network activity for your app. ...

To monitor threads, use [**CPU Profiler**](https://developer.android.com/studio/profile/cpu-profiler) in Android Profiler.

> 1. Click **View > Tool Windows > Android Profiler** (you can also click **Android Profiler** in the toolbar).
> 2. Select the device and app process you want to profile from the Android Profiler toolbar. If you've connected a device over USB but don't see it listed, ensure that you have enabled USB debugging.
> 3. Click anywhere in the **CPU** timeline to open the CPU Profiler.

Answer (score 13):

#### For Android 3.6.3

1. click **Run > Debug 'app'** (or shift + F9)
2. In the window that popped up click on the top right corner to enable more tabs
3. Make sure that `Threads` tab is enabled:
   [See that `Threads` tab is enabled](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GiQ2L.png)
4. click on the bottom of the screen on `Debug` and click on the `Debugger` tab
5. click on the `Threads` tab and you will see the threads

#### Another option:

1. click **Run > Profiler 'app'**
2. Expand window to fit full screen
3. click on the `CPU` area: [Click on the area where it shows CPU activity](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cer3H.png)
4. click on to expand `Threads`: [Click on threads to expand them](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EtJSo.png)

Answer (score 3):

You can monitor your threads in Android Device Monitor.

**Step 1:** 
Open Android Device Monitor like:
Android Studio -> Tools -> Android -> Android Device Monitor

**Step 2:**
Operate your App.

**Step 3:**
Select debugged process on **Devices** tab and select **Threads** tab on the right.

[image]

You can click any thread to see its trace. And you can also click **Refresh** to refresh all threads' status.

Comment: step 1 does not exist on my android studio

Answer (score 3):

In debug mode: at the bottom of androidStudio, click on:
 `Debug` -> `Debugger` -> `Threads`

Answer (score 2):

There is a Debug tab at the bottom of the screen. You can use the debugger to monitor various resources and variables of your app.
If you can't find the debugger at the bottom of the screen, Select **View > Tool Windows > Debug** or press **Alt+5**. The threads tab will be in the debugger.
 If you still cannot find the Threads tab in the debugger, you'll find an **icon that looks like a couple of boxes** with a drop-menu by the **top-right corner of the debugger**. Inside this drop-down list, make sure Threads option is checked.

[Here is a link](https://codelabs.developers.google.com/codelabs/android-training-using-debugger/index.html?index=..%2F..android-training#3) explaining Debugging

[image: debugger View]