# How could I know what the number of threads is used by specific coroutines dispatcher?

Tags: android, kotlin, kotlin-coroutines

How could I know what the number of threads Dispatchers.IO is currently using ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As you can read [here](https://kotlin.github.io/kotlinx.coroutines/kotlinx-coroutines-core/kotlinx.coroutines/-dispatchers/-i-o.html) `Dispatchers.IO` doesn't have own pool of threads, it uses a shared pool. `Dispatchers.Default` uses the same pool of threads. There no simple way to get active threads currently used by `Dispatchers.IO`. But you can try get thread count inside shared pool of threads.
The common pool of threads is creating inside [`CommonPool.kt`](https://github.com/Kotlin/kotlinx.coroutines/blob/e06b6caac44b87d698ab54049ae6f6ecfa382de6/core/kotlinx-coroutines-core/src/main/kotlin/kotlinx/coroutines/experimental/CommonPool.kt). It can create own pool or use [ForkJoinPool](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/ForkJoinPool.html). All threads created in pool have a specific name. So you can find all active thread of shared pool by name.

```
val threads = Thread.getAllStackTraces().keys.filter {
    it.name.startsWith("CommonPool") || it.name.startsWith("ForkJoinPool")
}
threads.size
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the Android profiler to monitor threads.

[Android Monitor tools](https://developer.android.com/studio/profile/am-basics) were replaced with [**Android Profiler**](https://developer.android.com/studio/profile/), in [Android Studio 3.0](https://android-developers.googleblog.com/2017/10/android-studio-30.html):

> **Android Profiler** - Android Studio 3.0 includes a brand new suite of tools to help debug performance problems in your app. We completely rewrote the previous set of Android Monitor tools, and replaced them with the Android Profiler. Once you deploy your app to a running device or emulator, click on the Android Profiler tab and you will now have access to a real-time & unified view of the CPU, Memory, & Network activity for your app. ...

To monitor threads, use [**CPU Profiler**](https://developer.android.com/studio/profile/cpu-profiler) in Android Profiler.

> 1. Click **View > Tool Windows > Android Profiler** (you can also click **Android Profiler** in the toolbar).
> 2. Select the device and app process you want to profile from the Android Profiler toolbar. If you've connected a device over USB but don't see it listed, ensure that you have enabled USB debugging.
> 3. Click anywhere in the **CPU** timeline to open the CPU Profiler.

From: https://stackoverflow.com/a/50691178/2675353