# Horizontal Recyclerview not scrolling properly

Tags: android, android-recyclerview

I have a `fragment` `layout` that is a part of a `PageViewer`.

The `fragment` has 2 `RecyclerViews` - one on the top of the `layout` which is horizontal, the other one at the bottom which is vertical.

Here is my XML :

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_margin="7dp"
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:text="@string/fragment_marketplace_marketplace_title"
        android:textSize="30sp"
        android:textStyle="bold" />

    <SearchView
        android:id="@+id/fragment_marketplace_searchview"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:queryHint="Search..."
        app:iconifiedByDefault="false"
        tools:layout_editor_absoluteX="1dp"
        tools:layout_editor_absoluteY="1dp" />

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginStart="14dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="14dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="15dp"
        android:text="@string/fragment_marketplace_discover_products_from_myverte"
        android:textSize="17sp"
        android:textStyle="bold" />

    <android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
        android:id="@+id/fragment_marketplace_brands_recycler_view"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginTop="15dp"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        app:layoutManager="android.support.v7.widget.LinearLayoutManager"
        tools:listitem="@layout/fragment_marketplace_vendor_row_item" />

    <android.support.v4.widget.NestedScrollView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:orientation="vertical">

            <TextView
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginStart="14dp"
                android:layout_marginLeft="14dp"
                android:background="@color/very_light_grey"
                android:paddingTop="15dp"
                android:text="@string/fragment_marketplace_featured_products"
                android:textSize="17sp"
                android:textStyle="bold" />

            <android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
                android:id="@+id/fragment_marketplace_products_recycler_view"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:layout_gravity="center"
                android:background="@color/very_light_grey"
                tools:listitem="@layout/fragment_marketplace_products_row_item" />

        </LinearLayout>

    </android.support.v4.widget.NestedScrollView>




</LinearLayout>
```

[image]

1) When scrolling left/right the scrolling sometimes gets stuck and not responsive. Why does this happen?

2) How do I make the `view` shows some part of the next views in the list, so it will make the filling of an actual `scrollable` list and not just a stale image?

edit -

here is my row item xml -

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="200dp"
    android:padding="10dp">

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/vendorImageview"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:src="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.5"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />


</android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>
```

edit -

my recyclerview initing -

```java
private void initViews(View view) {
        gson = new Gson();
        miniVendorModelList = new ArrayList<>();
        miniProductModelList = new ArrayList<>();
        searchView = view.findViewById(R.id.fragment_marketplace_searchview);
        Drawable drawable = getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.search_widget_very_light_grey_background);
        searchView.setBackground(drawable);

        //adapters
        vendorsAdapter = new VendorAdapter(miniVendorModelList);
        productsAdapter = new ProductsAdapter(miniProductModelList, getContext());

        //lists
        vendorsList = view.findViewById(R.id.fragment_marketplace_brands_recycler_view);
        productsList = view.findViewById(R.id.fragment_marketplace_products_recycler_view);
        vendorsList.setNestedScrollingEnabled(false);
        productsList.setNestedScrollingEnabled(false);

        //brands recycler
        vendorsList.setHasFixedSize(true);
        vendorsList.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(getContext(),LinearLayoutManager.HORIZONTAL, false));
        vendorsList.setAdapter(vendorsAdapter);

        //products recycler
        productsList.setLayoutManager(new GridLayoutManager(getContext(), 2));
        productsList.setHasFixedSize(true);
        productsList.setAdapter(productsAdapter);

    }
```

my adapter -

```java
package com.twoverte.adapters;

import android.support.annotation.NonNull;
import android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;

import com.twoverte.R;
import com.twoverte.adapters.holder.VendorsHolder;
import com.twoverte.models.Vendor.MiniVendorModel;

import java.util.ArrayList;

public class VendorAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<VendorsHolder> {

    private ArrayList<MiniVendorModel> miniVendorModels;

    public VendorAdapter(ArrayList<MiniVendorModel> miniVendorModels) {
        this.miniVendorModels = miniVendorModels;
    }

    @NonNull
    @Override
    public VendorsHolder onCreateViewHolder(@NonNull ViewGroup viewGroup, int i) {
        View view = LayoutInflater.from(viewGroup.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.fragment_marketplace_vendor_row_item, viewGroup, false);
        return new VendorsHolder(view);
    }

    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(@NonNull VendorsHolder vendorsHolder, int i) {
        MiniVendorModel model = miniVendorModels.get(i);
        Picasso.get().load(model.getImageURL()).memoryPolicy(MemoryPolicy.NO_CACHE).into(vendorsHolder.vendorImageView);
    }

    @Override
    public int getItemCount() {
        return miniVendorModels.size();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

> How do I make the view shows some part of the next views in the list, so it will make the filling of an actual scrollable list and not just a stale image?

What you can do here is make your `layout/fragment_marketplace_vendor_row_item` occupy say 80% width also add some padding

**update width to 80%**

```
 android:layout_width="0dp"
 android:layout_weight="0.8"
```

> When scrolling left/right the scrolling sometimes gets stuck and not responsive. Why does this happen?

this might have been [answered here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33288436/recyclerview-laggy-scrolling)

Comment: I have added my row item xml. How can I make it 80% width? Also, I have tried the link of that thread, nothing helped

Comment: are you running a thread on the main thread maybe like the thread that feeds your recycler view

Comment: how to check running threads https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39031060/is-there-a-way-to-monitor-threads-in-androidstudio

Comment: added my java function that inits the RV & adapter variables, will add also my adapter

Answer (score 1):

Found a solution for bad scrolling - wrapped the horizontal RV with a `NestedScrollView`. Works perfectly, I have no idea why. Just trial and error.

If someone knows why this works it would be awesome.